# Laravel project, how to make public folder not accessable by root

Tags: php, laravel

I have my Laravel project that is hosted on a server, I made a copy of that project for testing and development on my local pc, but there is a difference that I don't know how to solve. On my local pc I do not need to specify public folder to access css files and other stuff, but on my server I have to specify, otherwise I doesn't find those files in public folder.
Example code on server:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/public/css/main.css">
```

And on my local pc

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/main.css">
```

So I would love to make this thing the same on my local project, because now everytime I push changes to the server I need to add public to all the stuff and that's annoying. If I understand correctly it is done for security purposes, but I don't know how to make it on my project.

Comment: It means, your server is not pointing it's `DocumentRoot` (if it is an apache server) to `PROJECT_ROOT/public`, you MUST point the root of the page to the `public` folder...

Comment: @matiaslauriti why it is a must thing? I am using cloud services for my web app, maybe it's their policy to not point to that folder, but at least I would like to replicate that on my local pc

Comment: Read the [Directory structure documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/structure#the-public-directory) and the [Deployment documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/deployment#server-configuration)

Answer (score -1):

Use Laravel asset() function like below,

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('css/main.css')}}">
```

Comment: Yes it works on my local pc, but if I push this change to the server, it still do not find those files. When I open dev console it shows that the structure of my app is: example.com -> public -> css, but on my local pc it is example.com -> css, so in when I get in my app it sees public folder, that is why is have specify "public" in my code

Comment: try with public_path() function like this, public_path('css/main.css')

Comment: did you run `php artisan storage:link`: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem#the-public-disk